# How to find out which tty a command was run in?

Tags: bash, terminal, tty

Web search found e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/624848/view-history-of-commands-run-in-terminal, from which I understood there is the file `~/.bash_history` and the temp history.

I have many terminals open and want to find out specific output, `history` shows me command I've interested in. Any way to find out what `tty` it was run in?

P.S. [bash history where command run](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349443/bash-history-where-command-run) discusses folders in file system for `where`.

Comment: `ps` may be able to provide that information **if** you're talking about active processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't identify this retrospectively from the bash history file. However, you might get somewhere with `lastcomm` if it's installed and active.

Going forward there's nothing stopping you having different history files for different terminals. Put this into your `~/.bashrc` (and maybe your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` too):

```
# Per-terminal history files
[ -n "$HISTFILE" ] && tty=$(tty 2>/dev/null) && HISTFILE="$HOME/.bash_history${tty//\//_}"
```